Can anyone identify this “fruit”?
Just found this “fruit” in my driveway, probably dropped by a bird.  I opened to see what kind of seed was inside.  Does anyone know what this is and is it edible?
I live in the San Fernando Valley of Southern California, USA.


Could you include a photograph with something other than a coin in your local currency so those of us not familiar with US coins can get an idea of the size? Also, I take it all of those seeds came from that one fruit, right?

Unfortunately, I no longer have the fruit in order to take another picture.  It was about an inch long and had about a dozen seeds.
